# Which test would be best for my thesis study with 2 variables and 2 levels? I'm considering to run on SPSS, 4 separate correlation tests, OR a MLR

Tags: correlation, multiple-regression, spss, stepwise-regression, psychology

My thesis questions on whether a certain type of thoughts are associated with stress levels. There are two types of thoughts and two different levels. What should I use? The first variable is the direction of thoughts (upwards vs downwards) and the controllability of thoughts (controllable vs uncontrollable). I also considered doing stepwise regression to talk about the potential interactions.

This is a psychology study. Really appreciate the help :)

Comment: do you have a regression problem (e.g. a response variable and some covariates) or do you want to test for association between two qualitative variables?

Comment: Hi Utobi, thank you for your response. I'm simply testing for the association. So the plan is really to look at whether upward comparative thoughts were associated with higher levels of stress, and whether downward comparative thoughts were associated with lower levels of stress. Same goes for the controllability of it. I had surveyed stress levels on a Likert scale of 1-5. :)

Comment: you may have a look at this `R`-based (though not `SPSS`) answer https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/591851/using-chi-squared-test-to-compare-distributions-in-r/591955#591955

Comment: hmm... in that case, will cramer's V work? Since I will need to use SPSS?

Comment: Cramer's V is a normalized version of the chi-squared statistic and is useful for measuring the strength of the association. It can also be to test for the presence of association but it shouldn't add very much to the chi-squared test https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/585828/how-are-the-confidence-interval-of-cramers-v-and-the-chi-square-statistic-relat

Comment: If you found my answer useful, please consider accepting it by clicking on the tick mark. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If the sample size is small it is advisable to use [Fisher's exact test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_test) which provides an exact p-value.

With large samples, you may use a chi-squared test or the [G-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G-test).

I'm not familiar with SPSS but by searching the web, I think you will be able to find tutorials on how to run Fisher's exact test and the chi-squared test in SPSS.

Comment: here is a tutorial on Fisher's exact test in SPSS https://www.scalestatistics.com/fishers-exact-test.html